# bash script to clean up jenkins agent workspace once a week

Tags: bash, jenkins, cron

How to write a bash script that runs based on a schedule in order to clean up the workspace on jenkins agent where builds have accumulated? job should run on a specific day of the week. I have tried several approaches but fail as job tries to delete it self from its own workspace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use [Workspace cleanup plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?query=workspace%20cleanup) as a final poay-build atep to clean up after themselves. There's lots of scripts out there already to clean nodes. Usually Groovy is preferred since it knows about Jenkins workspace and what's not orphaned